# Problem when trying to add Prettier's Git Hook: husky install error `install command is deprecated`

Tags: githooks, husky, prettier-eslint

node version: 20.11.0
pnpm version: 8.15.0
os: Windows

I was following the instructions in https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html

- I ran the second command `pnpm exec husky install` and
- cmd gives me an ERROR message "install command is deprecated"

Is there a problem with husky? How to setup prettier git hook?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 9):

From the [husky v9.0.1 changelog](https://github.com/typicode/husky/releases/tag/v9.0.1)

> Removed `husky install`. Use `husky` or `husky some/dir` for the same functionality (deprecation notice to be added).

Comment: Thank you phil. So if i understand correctly, `husky install` is now `husky init`. And what about adding new precommit hook e.g. `pnpm exec husky add .husky/pre-commit "pnpm exec lint-staged"`? From the link you gave it will be `echo "pnpm exec lint-staged" > .husky/pre-commit`? This does not make sense. Echo is to printout on command line right?

Comment: @KJAng yes, `echo` will print the statement, but you are redirecting the output with the `>`. This means that instead of printing it to the command line it will create `.husky/pre-commit` with the contents that you have echoed, in this instance `pnpm exec lint-staged`